# Hashed file names using Rollup

Tags: hash, rollupjs

I am fairly new to bundlers and `rollup` specifically.  What is the best way to conditionally hash file names in `rollup.config.js` when building for production,  while at the same time saving the `index.html` to reference the new `.css` and `.js`  hashed versions?

I see this in the [docs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputentryfilenames), but I guess I don't know how to conditionally set these options based on `dev/prod` settings?

```
output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
       // entryFileNames : 'bundle[hash].js
    },
```

or is using `rollup-plugin-hash` a better solution? 
still not sure what the best practice would be for updating the `index.html` 
(and what does the manifest file option provide?)

Comment: Just a comment. If you use entryFileNames and file options together, entryFileNames will be disregarded. You have to use dir option to specify the base folder name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a plugin like [@rollup/plugin-html](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/html) to generate a html file that references the hashed filenames.

It is also possible to use the [rollup-plugin-manifest](https://github.com/shuizhongyueming/rollup-plugin-output-manifest) to generate a JSON file that will contain these hashed filenames.
This is useful when you can't generate the HTML using rollup for some reason.

Since the Rollup config file is just Javascript, you can include some [if statements that return different results](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#plugins) based on the dev/prod settings.

```
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

export default {
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'app',
    entryFileNames: isProduction ? 'bundle[hash].js' : 'public/build/bundle.js',
    dir: './',
  }
};
```

see [output.entryFileNames](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-entryfilenames)