# Vue WebApp - Load latest build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, browser-cache, bootstrap-vue

I'm building a Vue.js application using Vuexy BootstrapVue template, deployed in a Docker container.

I am finding that when we deploy updates to our web app, that the User has to do a hard-refresh in their browser to load the latest version of the app, otherwise they'll be navigating around a cached version.

Is there a way for me to force a client browser to load the latest version for a User?
Either on every load, or every few hours?

(I've tagged Bootstrap-Vue for transparency, but don't actually know if it has any bearing on this issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing the cache problem and there is multiple ways to handle this.

### Cache Control

You can control the cache with the header with `max-age` or `no-store`, `no-cache` to simple disable it, like this question/answer: [How do we control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control
https://csswizardry.com/2019/03/cache-control-for-civilians/

### Cache busting

Aappending a version (example: 1.0.0) to query string of the script tag:

```
<script src="path/to/your/app.min.js?v=1.0.0"
```

and change that version for every build.

### Hashing the script file

You can also use some webpack/rollup config to build the script with a hash, like `app.bf43112.js`

#### webpack

```json
const config = {
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
  },
};
```

#### Rollup

```json
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

export default {
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'app',
    file: isProduction ? 'bundle[hash].js' : 'public/build/bundle.js',
  }
};
```

Reference: [Hashed file names using Rollup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115750/hashed-file-names-using-rollup)

### Service Worker

Another solution, that I never tested, but sounds a good method.. is creating a service worker to control how retrieve the js file:
https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

You can do things like deleting the cache, responding the cache with a response that you manually fetch with js, etc.